# Navigation with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, navigation, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Sorry for my english :))

I use UIPageViewController for navigate between pages. The first page is the table of content for all pages. When I click on element in table of content, I tried to change page with the method above :

```
-(void) flipToPage:(int)index {
BaseArtViewController *pageViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pageViewController, nil];

if (currentIndex < index){
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
else if (currentIndex > index){
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

// For change pageControl aspect
NSArray *subviews = self.pageController.view.subviews;
UIPageControl *thisControl = nil;
for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
        thisControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        thisControl.currentPage = index;
    }
}
```

}

It's work but not properly, there's no transition between the table of content and the page accessing.

When I arrive on clicked page, if I try to access previous page, example I'm on page 4, I want to go on page 3 but I return on page 0 (table of content). Do you know a solution or someone can explain me how to do that ???

Thanks for help !

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController methods.

Comment: 1) Are the indexes for the view controller pages set up correctly so they return 0 for the first page, 1 for the second page, etc.? 2) Is the method viewControllerAtIndex implemented such that it returns the correct view controller page for the specified index? Also, it doesn't look like you are initializing currentIndex, and I think you should set it to "index" in flipToPage after the "if" statements.

Comment: Each indexes are correct. The method `viewControllerAtIndex` work correctly. Property `currentIndex` is defined in `viewDidLoad` with value 0 for the first page. I've tried to change index in `flipToPage` but nothing change. When I return on previous page the first time, I access to table of content page. I can publish complete classes if necessary.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with what you posted so far. I've implemented very similar code and it works correctly. I can move directly to any page and then move backward and forward from that point.

Comment: Maybe I can find the problem if you post the code that creates the view controller pages.

Comment: I edit my previous message with code. If you want, I can post you via mail or share via a link all classes. Thanks for your help...

Comment: It looks like the issue is in the viewControllerAtIndex method. If you post that method, I think I can help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Here is my code :

```
-(UIViewController*) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [(BaseArtViewController *)viewController index];
    NSLog(@"Index Before : %i", index);

    if (index == 0) return nil;

    // Change index
    index--;

    // Stock current index
    currentIndex = index;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}


-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [(BaseArtViewController *)viewController index];
    NSLog(@"Index After : %i", index);

    // Change index
    index++;

    if (index == nbPages) return nil;

    // Stock current index
    currentIndex = index;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

And for initialization :

```
-(void) initPresentation {
    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    BaseArtViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentIndex];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

---

Base Class : BaseArtViewController.h
    #import

```
@interface BaseArtViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSArray *tabS;

@end
```

Base Class : BaseArtViewController.m

```
#import "BaseArtViewController.h"

@interface BaseArtViewController ()
@end

@implementation BaseArtViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"Index Page : %i", self.index);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```